# Immediately check if field content already exists in a node form

Tags: forms, ajax, nodes

I am struggling with a problem which I thought might be answered simply... Any help would be appreciated!

I have a content type called 'review'. Each review has a field called 'location'. As a user creates a new review, once they have filled in the location field, I would like a small message to appear in case that same user has already created a review for the same location.

Doing it when the user is about to save the node is not too complicated. But I actually want it to happen as soon as the relevant field is not empty.

Thanks

Comment: How did you solved this ?

Comment: Sorry Devidas, I have had to put this aside. No solution yet. (I have not tried the proposed anwer below, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

You can write little custom jQuery snippet using 'blur' event in order to do this. More information you may find on this page http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp